android kotlin error : java.lang.runtimeException
cannot generate view binders java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found: string date_format.
We are working on an Android studio project. The language is kotlin. An error occurred, but I don't know why.
I think I need to modify the "Gradle (app)" but I don't know how to add or change it

How about reading the error message instead of jumping to conclusions? It clearly tells: R.string.date_format is missing or you may have imported the wrong one class R.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string name="date_format">some date format string</string>
</resources>


Thank you very much. I've been having a hard time with the error for a month, and it makes me laugh that it was a really small problem. Thank you
